# retrieving listrow data Android

Tags: android

I have a list of Strings and every row has a button next to it. If the user clicks the button i want to retrieve the data for that row from the onClickListener. This sounds like impossible because there's no way I can retrieve data from a list without onItemClick. Is there a way to accomplish this with a button click instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you know the position in the list from the onclickevent, right? So you could call the getItem with that position?

Comment: actually no, i don't know the position. Sorry for my newbieness :(

Comment: Alternately just pull that item at the index specified by "position" from the String array you have tied to the ListAdapter. (e.g. `stringArray[position]`)

Comment: I didn't know i needed the onClickListener in the getView method in the class extends BaseAdapter. But anyways, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

That's the thing, i don't have a position in the clickListener:

```
addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {

           }
       });
```